# The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I referred several websites, which had answer for this question
"The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required." ,but none were helpful. 
I wrote a sample code to check the proxy authentication in office. The code throws exception.

My requirement:- Verify what the website returns. Outside office, the code works fine, but in office it throws an exception due to proxy.
When I hardcode the credentials using new NetworkCredential, it works fine.

```
int ResponseCode;
string url = "http://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt";
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);

request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
 {

   Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
   responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
   ResponseCode = (int)((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode;
   reader.Close();
}
```

I do not want to Hardcode. I referred the solution in http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/csharpgeneral/thread/c06d3032-dceb-4a1a-bb6a-778fd13a938a, but even that didnt help.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue, this did the trick for me

request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

Answer (score 4):

There are many things here. You can try setting Credentials explicitly

```
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredentials(username, password)
```

You might need to specify proxy. By default it uses your IE proxy. You might not want that

```
WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://stackoverflow.com/");
webRequest.Proxy = new WebProxy("http://proxyserver:80/",true);
```

Comment: 1) It works when I set the credentials explicitly. But it wont work if I give this app to another user.

Comment: I need to have common solution. 2) How helpful will it be to specify a proxy? Will it be accepted globally (meaning- will I be able to use this app in any office network)? If yes then I am happy to use it 3) Our program has several checks to verify a network connection. This code is one of the checks and is failing in office. We need to get it work without specifying credentials explicitly. @fenix2222- I appreciate your response. Thank you.

Comment: @user1473039 That means that you need to get infrastructure guys to enable access to external website "http://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt" or get them to create a service account that you can use rather than using your credentials. At the end of the day this is how it works. Alternatively, you could try to impersonate application so when it runs CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials will use windows credentials of the person running the app

Comment: Sounds strange that using a program I cannot get a response from a website even though internet is accessible. Using CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials doesn't helps. There should be some way to get the network credentials and pass it to the proxy.

Comment: @user1473039 As I said you might need to impoersonate application as the context under which application is running might not be your user account, hence CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials returns credentials of some other account

Comment: How do I impersonate application to use my windows credentials?

Comment: If this is a asp.net app here is how: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118(v=vs.71).aspx. You will need to have <authentication Mode="Windows" /> as well in your web.config

Comment: +1 for your answer. I got to know something new. But this is a C# console app that runs quietly in the background.

Comment: I can't see +1 :( If it works, mark it as an answer. By the way impersonation works for any type of app, just put it into app.config instead of web.config

Comment: Nopes, that doesnt work. But I owe you +1. I am worried if I am missing something or doing something silly

Comment: Try running System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name and see what username you get. Output it to console

Comment: So it should be running under that user account and CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials should return credentials of the currently logged in or impersonated user.

Comment: If it still doesn't work, then it is most likely double hop Kerberos issue which is a nigthmare and I cannot really suggest much, just read about it

Comment: This is what is expected that CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials should return credentials of the currently logged in. But its not catering to. The code would be as simple as 3 lines 'WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://stackoverflow.com/");
                webRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                webRequest.Method = "GET";
                WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse();'

Comment: I know this is an old post, but wanted to throw my two cents in anyway. Maybe I misunderstand the question, but why haven't you tried doing a check to discern if the user is accessing from inside the network versus outside the network, and then determine based on that which method to use?

Comment: +1 for the 'new WebProxy' statement - this solved the problem I was having because the DefaultCredentials were being applied to a 'dummy' proxy created by the WebRequest instead of to the real proxy.